# Cannot render events on FullCalendar from JSON feed

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, fullcalendar

I have a page that returns JSON info from a cfc. The JSON is an array of structures that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "allday": true,
    "title": "event1",
    "userid": 1,
    "end": "",
    "classname": "",
    "editable": true,
    "start": "2010-09-01",
    "id": 1,
    "url": ""
  },
  {
    "allday": true,
    "title": "event2",
    "userid": 1,
    "end": "",
    "classname": "",
    "editable": true,
    "start": "2010-09-10",
    "id": 2,
    "url": ""
  }
]
```

When I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Create JQuery connection to obj
    $('#event').hide();
    //Make event bubble draggable
    $('#event').draggable();

    $('#evBubbleClose').click(cleanEventBubble);
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            createEvent(date, allDay, jsEvent, view, this);
        },
        events: 'http://xxxxx/cfc/FullCalendarEvents.cfc?method=getEvents',
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true
    });
});
```

The events do not render. However, if I copy and paste the JSON in event: JSON Array here, it shows the events. What am I doing wrong that the events don't render from a feed?

Comment: Have you set your default view to month view? Maybe your calendar doesn't have in scope the dates you have fed into it. Just guessing, because the code seems right to me.

Comment: Is the JSON on the same server? events: 'cfc/FullCalendarEvents.cfc?method=getEvents',

Answer (score 1):

Where you are specifying a FQDN for your event URL, is it the same FQDN as the calling page?  If jQuery is used to call an AJAX function on a different domain, subdomain, or protocol (like calling http from https) then you must use a JSONP wrapper.

Details [about Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [jQuery annd JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: It was actually a stupid human error. ColdFusion was returning extra junk with the JSON content I had to disable that. It is working now